# Localizing 'AM' and 'PM' text in full calendar axis

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using FC 2.0 and was searching for an option to localize 'AM' 'PM' text on the axis, which is being set with the option:

```
        axisFormat: 'h(:mm) A',
```

is there a way to overwrite these values like we do for monthNames, dayNames etc?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
This is how I'm localizing some other elements of full calendar:

```
('#calendar-wrapper').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month,  today',
      center: 'prev,title,next',
      right: 'publish_info'
    },
    titleFormat: {
      month: 'MMM YYYY',
      agendaDay: 'dddd, MMM D YYYY',
      agendaWeek: 'MMM D, YYYY',
    },
    columnFormat: {
      week: 'ddd D'
    },
    axisFormat: 'h(:mm) A',
    buttonText: {
      day: I18n.t('day_button'),
      week: I18n.t('week_button'),
      month: I18n.t('month_button'),
      today: I18n.t('today')
    },
    lang: I18n.locale,
    monthNames: I18n.t('date.month_names'),
    monthNamesShort: I18n.t('date.abbr_month_names'),
    dayNames: I18n.t('date.day_names'),
    dayNamesShort: I18n.t('date.abbr_day_names'),
   ...
   // rest of the code..
```

The I18n.t('day_button') will contain the day text for selected language. 
Likewise I'd like to set something like I18n.t('am') and I18n.t('pm') to show the localized AM PM text on the axis.
Thanks

Comment: [axisFormat](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/axisFormat/) is deprecated, it has been renamed to [slotLabelFormat](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotLabelFormat/). Is that what you mean?

Comment: moment.js supports **LT** or **LTS** for localized time format http://momentjs.com/docs/#localized-formats

Comment: i literally want to change the text labels, "AM" and "PM". i don't want to change the time. For ex: "10:00 AM" in english sholuld show up like "10 ए एम" in hindi.

Comment: You can change the calendar [Language](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/lang/) to Hindi but this changes everything and not just the AM/PM label.

Comment: Even when i change the calendar lang to hindi, it still shows AM and PM in english only

Comment: That is odd, I just changed it by adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="lang/hi.js"></script>` below my `fullcalendar.min.js` and the entire calendar was rendered in Hindi.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I needed to override moments i18n meridiem function.

```
moment.lang(I18n.locale, {
  meridiem : function (hours, minutes, isLower) {
    return hours < 12 ? I18n.t('date.am') : I18n.t('date.pm');
  }
});
// I18n.locale is the current user's local
// and specified calendar locale to
// lang: I18n.locale
// date.pm, date.pm are placed in rails yaml files and will be loaded for selected language
```

Thanks